# Is it possible to use 'case' with and in 'count'?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to use `case` with and in `count`

```
 SELECT branches.NAME AS agence, 
       count( 
       CASE loanstatus 
              WHEN '1' 
              AND    Datepart(month,loanaccount.issuedate)= 2 THEN 1 
              ELSE NULL 
       END )AS nombre_de_credits_demande , 
       count( 
       CASE loanstatus 
              WHEN '2' datepart(month,loanaccount.chargeoffdate)= 2 THEN 1 
              ELSE NULL 
       END )AS nombre_de_credits_approuve
```

please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use it with `count()`.  I prefer `sum()`:

```
select Branches.Name as Agence,
       sum(case when LoanStatus = '1' and
                     datepart(MONTH, LoanAccount.IssueDate) = 2
                then 1 else 0
           end ) as Nombre_de_Crédits_Demandé ,
       sum(case when LoanStatus = '2' and
                     datepart(MONTH, LoanAccount.IssueDate) = 2
                then 1 else 0
           end ) as Nombre_de_Crédits_Approuvé
```

The issue with your code was not the `count()` versus `sum()` it is the mixing of two different `case` syntaxes.  When you use `case <var> when <val>`, you cannot include any other conditions.  Just use `when` with the full conditions that you want.

And, if you like, you can use `count()` instead of `sum()`.

And, for conciseness, I prefer the `month()` function:

```
select Branches.Name as Agence,
       sum(case when LoanStatus = '1' and MONTH(LoanAccount.IssueDate) = 2
                then 1 else 0
           end ) as Nombre_de_Crédits_Demandé ,
       sum(case when LoanStatus = '2' and MONTH(LoanAccount.IssueDate) = 2
                then 1 else 0
           end ) as Nombre_de_Crédits_Approuvé
```

Comment: Why do you choose `SUM` over `COUNT`. Is there any specific reason?

Comment: in this case SUM is essentially counting a ticker on a true condition.  A count would include 0 as a true tick, which you would not want included.

Comment: @Fireblade . . . I think it is more habit.  My personal reasoning is that `count()` checks for something not being `NULL`, and this check is irrelevant to the calculation being done.  So, I think that the `sum()` is a more direct method of implementing the logic.  Plus, I find it a bit confusing that `count(1)` and `count(2)` return the same value.

Comment: @BradD - You didn't get my point. Same thing can be achieved through `count` without using `Else` part in `case statement`. Read Gordan's comment that is why i asked.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - That sounds reasonable. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your goal through this query.

```
select
branches.name as agence
,(select COUNT(1) from <table_name> where loginstatus=1 and Datepart(month,loanaccount.issuedate)= 2) as nombre_de_credits_demande
,(select COUNT(1) from <table_name> where loginstatus=2 and Datepart(month,loanaccount.issuedate)= 2) as AS nombre_de_credits_approuve
from <Table_name>
```